# Bulk Addition SOAP/XML

Tags: java, xml, perl, soap

I have a SOAP/XML script that adds EmployeeIDs in a db as below.

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:sach="http://www.abc.com/SACHEmployeeProvision/">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <sach:EmployeeInfo EMPLOYEEID="123727396907">
<AttributeList Name = "EMPLOYEE" Value = "OHIO-123727396907"/>              
         <AttributeList Name = "NAME_GIVEN" Value = "abc"/>
         <AttributeList Name = "NAME_FAMILY" Value = "xyz"/>
         <AttributeList Name = "GENDER" Value = "F"/>
         <AttributeList Name = "LANGUAGE" Value = "E"/>
         <AttributeList Name = "STATUS" Value = "ACTIVE"/>
         </sach:EmployeeInfo>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>>
```

I currently use SOAPUI to add EMPLOYEEID one at a time. How do I do this in bulk? Perhaps using perl or java.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

For Java, you can use a [JAX-WS client](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/5/tutorial/doc/bnayn.html).

For Perl consider [SOAP::Lite](http://guide.soaplite.com/#writing%20a%20client).

Your answer doesn't specify whether you want to add a different employee ID for each employee and where you are getting that data, but given the tools to interface with SOAP in your chosen language you should be able to get started and ask further questions here as needed.